# DataTables JS - How can I filter the table using the mData value instead of the value of the mRender function?

Tags: select, filter, datatables, rendering, filtering

I'm using a DataTable that has the following column:

```
 {
   sTitle: "<?= $this->translate('page_type') ?>",
   sName:  "name",
   sClass: "capitalize",
   mData:  "type",
   mRender: function(data, type, full) {

       return full.translatedString;
   }
}
```

Through a custom form select I filter the table by type. The option values of the select are the same than the values of 'data' in the function mRender. I want to display on my table the full.translatedString but I want to filter the table through the 'data' value. Is it possible??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use 'type' parameter.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aljordan82/x59Fy/)

```
 mRender: function(data, type, full){
        if (type == "display" ){
          return full.translatedString;// return what you want to display             
        }
        return data;// return what you want to sort/filter by
    }
```